# sql select orders with similar items

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select those orders in pairs who have the same products in them. `ORDER_ITEMS` contain the product and a foreign key to reference the parent `ORDER` row.  Order rows need to be different.

I've managed to list out pairs with count how many matching products they have in them, but that's only a similarity count. I need to exclude orders from pairs who have different products in them.

Can have Oracle specific stuff in it.

The two tables are:

```
Order(order_id, customer_id...) 
Order_Item(item_id, order_id FK, product_id,...)
```

I need tose order_id-s that have all Order_Item childs with matching product_id-s.

Ex. in  Orders

```
{ (ord1, cust1)  
  (ord2, cust2)}
```

and in Order_Items

```
{ (item1, ord1, product_id=3),  
  (item2, ord1, product_id=6),   
  (item3, ord2, product_id=3),   
  (item4, ord2, product_id=6) }
```

So basically, two people bought exactly the same two things. They are a pair. Those orders whose ordered products don't match exactly are not listed.

Comment: So write your queries and maybe someone will help you. We won't do your homework tho.

Comment: We need the CREATE TABLE statements for both tables to know what columns there are.  Sample data and expected output based on the data would help us to be able to help you.  What version of Oracle?

Comment: Is the question better posed as: List the products used on more than one order, along with ORDER information?

Comment: No, i don't want to list the products, i wan to list orders with matching products (from orders i'll go and make it customers actually, but basic idea can be done on those 2 tables, no need to write here the whole schema) :)

Comment: The 2 tables are Order(order_id, customer_id...) and Order_Item(item_id, order_id FK, product_id,...). I need tose order_id-s that have all Order_Item childs with matching product_id-s. Ex. in Orders { (ord1, cust1) and (ord2, cust2)} and in Order_Items { (item1, ord1, product_id=3), (item2, ord1, product_id=6), (item3, ord2, product_id=3), (item4, ord2, product_id=6) } So basically 2 people bought exactly the same 2 things. They are a pair. Those orders who's ordered products don't match exactly are not listed.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified db version so I'm assuming 11g - not tested, but I think it will give you the general idea:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  WITH qry AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           order_id
          ,LISTAGG(product_id,'+')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_id)
           AS order_signature
    FROM   order_items
    GROUP BY order_id)
  SELECT order_id
        ,order_signature
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT order_id)
         OVER (PARTITION BY order_signature)
         count_same
  FROM   qry
) WHERE count_same > 1;
```

Limitation: it won't work if some orders are very big, e.g. 100s or 1000s of product IDs.

Comment: To be precise, you're assuming 11gR2.  `listagg()` isn't available in any earlier version.

Comment: For Oracle 10 you can replace listagg with wmsys.wm_concat(), although I do not recall if it is installed and public by default or if you need to get the DBA to make it available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your final data set needs to look like, but selecting from Customers with an EXISTS expression in the WHERE clause to look for order matches will get you there.